# Display data according to dates in a table using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display data in a table according to dates and currently am using the following code.

```
if($_GET){
$datefrom = $_GET['datefrom'];
$dateto = $_GET['dateto'];
$date0 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom . " +0 days"));
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom . " +1 days"));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom . " +2 days"));
$date3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom . " +3 days"));
$date4 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom . " +4 days"));
}
```

Then I am querying my database repeatedly using the following statements

```
        $stmtHR0 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Form_Date = '$date0' AND State = 'HR'");
        $numHR0 = $stmtHR0->rowCount();
        $stmtHR1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Form_Date = '$date1' AND State = 'HR'");
        $numHR1 = $stmtHR1->rowCount();
        $stmtHR2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Form_Date = '$date2' AND State = 'HR'");
        $numHR2 = $stmtHR2->rowCount();
        $stmtHR3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Form_Date = '$date3' AND State = 'HR'");
        $numHR3 = $stmtHR3->rowCount();
        $stmtHR4 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Form_Date = '$date4' AND State = 'HR'");
        $numHR4 = $stmtHR4->rowCount();
```

"HR" is just one of the states and I have 30 states to perform these queries on. The code works but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this and I would be grateful if experts can help me on this. Please forgive me as I am still learning PHP.

Comment: What is `$dateto` used for? And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Babblo, `$dateto` is used in another query where it is required to return results between two dates. There are a large number of registered users in my database and I am trying count them and display them in a table based upon date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with one query. Assuming `From_Date` field is `DATE` field type:

```php
if ($_GET) {
    $dateF = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['datefrom']));
    $dateT = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['dateto']));
    $sql = "
        SELECT   `From_Date`, COUNT(*) AS `count_num`
        FROM     `table`
        WHERE    `From_Date` BETWEEN '$dateF' AND '$dateT' AND `State` = 'HR'
        GROUP BY `From_Date`
        ORDER BY `From_Date` ASC
    ";
    // db fetch all
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code : 
actually you can use array for date

```
$date = array();
$date[0] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom . " +0 days"));
$date[1] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom . " +1 days"));
$date[2] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom . " +2 days"));
$date[3] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom . " +3 days"));
$date[4] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom . " +4 days"));

for($i = 0; $i<count($date); $i++{
    $query_temp[] = "(
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE Form_Date = '" . $date[$i]. "' AND State = 'HR'
        ) AS count" . $i;

}

$query = "SELECT " . implode(", ",$query_temp);
$stmtHR4 = $db->query($query);
```

hope this code can solve you problem